# How to store value passed by ajax to database?

Tags: php, ajax

I want to display data or value return by the ajax function to be store in php variable as mentioned below. Any help?
 This is my code

```
function getUserInfo() 
{
            $.ajax({
                url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token=' + acToken,
                data: null,
                success: function(resp) {
                    user    =   resp;
                    console.log(user);
                    $('#uName').text('Welcome ' + user.name);
                    $('#imgHolder').attr('src', user.picture);
                },
                dataType: "jsonp"
            });
        }


I want to display in php variable as 

$name=$_POST['uName'];
$pics=$_POST['imgHolder'];
echo $name;
echo $pics;
```

Comment: You have to look at this.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917576/how-to-pass-javascript-variables-to-php

Comment: Are you you asking how to retrieve POST data IN php, or are you asking how to retrieve POST data from a jQuery $ajax call? Also, what you've written there isn't POST at all -- it's GET.

Comment: Data *returned* by Ajax will be returned to the browser. PHP doesn't run at the browser end.

Comment: You've overridden the processing of the HTTP response to treat it as JSONP, but your PHP output anything close to being JSONP.

Answer (score 1):

I would use PHP to make the request and store the result in an array, since you need to use the result in php

```
 $acToken='your value';

 $result = file_get_content('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token='.$acToken);

 echo '<pre>';
 print_r($result);
 echo '<pre>';
```

make sure to assing a value to `$acToken`;

Comment: Same here, this has nothing to do with the original question? OP needs to clarify before we get any answers

Comment: the downvote wasn't me

Comment: lol not saying it was, only that the question is totally out of wack and unanswerable.

Comment: I think I address him how to get the values for php in the right direction......and you'r right

Comment: Sounds like common sense to me. If he needs to use the result in php, the way I see it, he can send another request or just make the initial request from php which is more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

In your javascript, create ajax post request to your php url:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "some.php",
    data: { uName: "John", imgHolder: "img" }
})
.done(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
```

For more information, you can read [jQuery AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) documentation

Answer (score 0):

try below:
    $name=$_POST['uName'];
    $pics=$_POST['imgHolder'];
    echo json_encode(array('name'=>$name,'pics'=>$pics));

as that help for you